# Fluid simulation problem

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have set two fluid sims up with the same settings. The tall one is working and the fat isn't. Why?

Blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RixIoagHAfQyhVYKxJgwd50fsP405hu0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

1. change fluid domain settings on both domains to modular and is resumable and resolution to 64

[image]

2. hit bake data for both domains

[image]

3. you get:

[image]